# when i try add new field in sale order and invoicing and create sale order and confirm it and create invoice my new field is not contain any data

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7, openerp-8

## when i make confirm sale order and i try make create invoice only fields of sale order that created but my new field not  create

[when create invoice picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HoD6.png)

[my new field not contain information picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkTcA.png)

## mymodel.py

class sale_vehicle_direction(models.Model):

```
  _inherit = 'sale.order'
  vehicle_id = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle', 'Vehicle Model', store=True, select=True, required=True,
                             readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
  date_orderc = fields.Date('Date', select=True, required=True)
```

class invoice_vehicle_direction(models.Model):

```
_inherit = 'account.invoice'
vehicle_id = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle', 'VehicleModel',store=True, select=True, required=True)
```

class Do_create_invoices(models.Model):

```
_inherit = 'sale.advance.payment.inv'

def _prepare_advance_invoice_vals(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    sale_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
    ir_property_obj = self.pool.get('ir.property')
    fiscal_obj = self.pool.get('account.fiscal.position')
    inv_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
    wizard = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context)
    wizard.vehicle_id = wizard.vehicle_id_invoice
    sale_ids = context.get('active_ids', [])

    result = []
    for sale in sale_obj.browse(cr, uid, sale_ids, context=context):
        val = inv_line_obj.product_id_change(cr, uid, [], wizard.product_id.id,
                                             False, partner_id=sale.partner_id.id,
                                             fposition_id=sale.fiscal_position.id,
                                             company_id=sale.company_id.id)
        res = val['value']

        # determine and check income account
        if not wizard.product_id.id:
            prop = ir_property_obj.get(cr, uid,
                                       'property_account_income_categ', 'product.category', context=context)
            prop_id = prop and prop.id or False
            account_id = fiscal_obj.map_account(cr, uid, sale.fiscal_position or False, prop_id)
            if not account_id:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Configuration Error!'),
                                     _('There is no income account defined as global property.'))
            res['account_id'] = account_id
        if not res.get('account_id'):
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Configuration Error!'),
                                 _('There is no income account defined for this product: "%s" (id:%d).') % \
                                 (wizard.product_id.name, wizard.product_id.id,))

        # determine invoice amount
        if wizard.amount <= 0.00:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Incorrect Data'),
                                 _('The value of Advance Amount must be positive.'))
        if wizard.advance_payment_method == 'percentage':
            inv_amount = sale.amount_untaxed * wizard.amount / 100
            if not res.get('name'):
                res['name'] = self._translate_advance(cr, uid, percentage=True,
                                                      context=dict(context, lang=sale.partner_id.lang)) % (
                                  wizard.amount)
        else:
            inv_amount = wizard.amount
            if not res.get('name'):
                # TODO: should find a way to call formatLang() from rml_parse
                symbol = sale.pricelist_id.currency_id.symbol
                if sale.pricelist_id.currency_id.position == 'after':
                    symbol_order = (inv_amount, symbol)
                else:
                    symbol_order = (symbol, inv_amount)
                res['name'] = self._translate_advance(cr, uid, context=dict(context,
                                                                            lang=sale.partner_id.lang)) % symbol_order

        # determine taxes
        if res.get('invoice_line_tax_id'):
            res['invoice_line_tax_id'] = [(6, 0, res.get('invoice_line_tax_id'))]
        else:
            res['invoice_line_tax_id'] = False

        # create the invoice
        inv_line_values = {
            'name': res.get('name'),
            'origin': sale.name,
            'account_id': res['account_id'],
            'price_unit': inv_amount,
            'quantity': wizard.qtty or 1.0,
            'discount': False,
            'uos_id': res.get('uos_id', False),
            'product_id': wizard.product_id.id,
            'service_id': wizard.service_id.id,
            'invoice_line_tax_id': res.get('invoice_line_tax_id'),
            'account_analytic_id': sale.project_id.id or False,
        }
        inv_values = {
            'name': sale.client_order_ref or sale.name,
            'origin': sale.name,
            'type': 'out_invoice',
            'reference': False,
            'account_id': sale.partner_id.property_account_receivable.id,
            'partner_id': sale.partner_invoice_id.id,
            'vehicle_id': sale.vehicle_invoice_id.id,
            'invoice_line': [(0, 0, inv_line_values)],
            'currency_id': sale.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
            'comment': sale.note,
            'payment_term': sale.payment_term.id,
            'fiscal_position': sale.fiscal_position.id or sale.partner_id.property_account_position.id,
            'section_id': sale.section_id.id,
        }
        result.append((sale.id, inv_values))
        result.update((sale.id, inv_values))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In inv_vals dict you have a key called `'vehicle_id'` its value should be `sale.vehicle_id.id` also note that the class you inherit is `TransientModel` not `Models`

Comment: thanks asmaa  
i fixed it  . it must be like this 
 'vehicle_id_invoice': sale.vehicle_id.id,

where vehicle_id_invoice is a new field created in invoice model 
and sale.vehicle_id.id is a new field in sale order must passed its value to vehicle_id_invoice